# Format date events to dd-mm-yyyy in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I have a database, where there dates who are in format like 21-01-2023 but fullcalendar read dates like 2023-01-20.

I would like to read dates events like 21-01-2023 14:55.

I set lang to fr but just change the language not the the format date.

Any advice or tips would be appreciate.

Thanks.

there is example code of what i want to (see the third events example please)
the sample code :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Translate FullCalendar v2</h2>
    <center>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
    </center>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/lang-all.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          lang: 'fr',
                events: [
                        {
                          title: 'All Day Event',
                          start: '2023-01-01'
                        },
                        {
                          title: 'Long Event',
                          start: '2023-01-07',
                          end: '2023-01-10'
                        },
                        {
                          title: 'Long Event in my format date i want',
                          start: '20-01-2023',
                          end: '21-01-2023'
                        },
                ]
      });
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in javascript while assigning value you can use str.split('-').reverse().join('-') to change format

Comment: Are the dates in your database stored as strings (varchar)? Or are they stored as `DATE` or `DATETIME`? If the latter, they are _not_ stored formatted in a specific way. If the former, convert to the latter.

Comment: `I have a database, where there dates who are in format like 21-01-2023`...assuming they're actually _stored_ like that in a `varchar` column, then this is a really bad design flaw which you need to fix before doing anything else. As far as the computer is concerned, dates are _not_ text. You only need to convert them to a specific text format when displaying them to a human. If you store the dates in a generic format as DATETIME, then you can be very flexible and provide them to other applications, and to humans, in any (localised or generic) format they require.

Comment: And also, if you store dates in the DB properly, you can do useful things in SQL like sort them correctly, filter your rows by date, and so on. It's a no-brainer. Fix that, and then you won't have to worry about fullcalendar reading them correctly.

Comment: P.S. Why are you using such an ancient version of fullCalendar? If this is a new application, you should certainly use the latest version (v6).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `moment` to parse your dates as follows :

```
moment("20-01-2023", "DD-MM-YYYY")
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          lang: 'fr',
                events: [
                        {
                          title: 'All Day Event',
                          start: '2023-01-01'
                        },
                        {
                          title: 'Long Event',
                          start: '2023-01-07',
                          end: '2023-01-10'
                        },
                        {
                          title: 'Long Event 2',
                          start: moment("20-01-2023", "DD-MM-YYYY"),
                          end: moment('21-01-2023',"DD-MM-YYYY")
                        },
                ]
      });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Translate FullCalendar v2</h2>
    <center>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
    </center>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/lang-all.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or just use plain js Date. Moment themselves dont recommend their library anymore:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/